# How to include a module to multiple component with Dagger2?

Tags: android, data-binding, dagger-2

First, I had googled several things but couldn't make it. I have 2 components which are for the app and another one is for `DataBinding` as below:

> AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<FanseeApp> {

    @Override
    void inject(FanseeApp instance);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        AppComponent.Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

> BindingComponent

```
@DataBinding
@Component(dependencies = AppComponent.class, modules = {BindingModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface BindingComponent extends DataBindingComponent {}
```

And I want to use `SharedPreferences` for both of the components. It is placed in the AppModule However, I am getting the error below:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.app.Application cannot be provided
>   without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public interface BindingComponent extends DataBindingComponent {}
>          ^
>         android.app.Application is injected at
>             com.nuhkoca.fansee.di.module.ContextModule.bindsContext(application)
>         android.content.Context is injected at
>             com.nuhkoca.fansee.di.module.AppModule.provideSharedPreference(context)
>         android.content.SharedPreferences is injected at
>             com.nuhkoca.fansee.util.PreferenceUtil(sharedPreferences)
>         com.nuhkoca.fansee.util.PreferenceUtil is injected at
>             com.nuhkoca.fansee.di.module.BindingModule.bindsSpannableTextBindingAdapter(preferenceUtil)
>         com.nuhkoca.fansee.binding.SpannableTextBindingAdapter is provided at
>             androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent.getSpannableTextBindingAdapter()

How do I have the same module with multiple components? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: That's not what the error is saying.  The error is saying it doesn't know how to provide an Application, which something is asking to be injected.  You need in some module to provide Application, probably via explicit @Provides method (since the framework constructs it for you).

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan how can I introduce Application to my other components then?

Comment: You need a function in a module (generally your highest level module) that returns the Application object and has an @Provides annotation on it.  Generally you do that by saving it in a static variable in onCreate of the Application, and returning that saved static variable from your provides annotation